# Type error: Argument 2 passed to Controller::createFormBuilder() must be of the type array, object given, called in

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, session

I using symfony forms to create a form on html to update column value in my database table 
but when i run my code i get this error

in this line

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(new User(), $investor)
```

my user entity file

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
     /**
     *@var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="MatchP",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $MatchP;
    public function getMatchP()
    {
        return $this->MatchP;
    }

    public function setMatchP($MatchP)
    {
        $this->MatchP = $MatchP;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

my twig file code

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

my default controller file

```
<?php

namespace site\blogBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
      //$task = new User();
      $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

      $investor = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getId()));
      $MatchP = $investor->getMatchP();
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder(new User(), $investor)
          ->add('MatchP', TextType::class)
          ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->getForm();

      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           if(!empty($form->get('MatchP')->getData())){
               $investor->setMatchP($form->get('MatchP')->getData());
           }
           else{
               $investor->setMatchP($MatchP);
           }

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->persist($investor);
           $em->flush();

           $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
           $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Votre profil a été correctement modifié');


          return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
         }

      return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
      ));       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument for `createFormBuilder()` or `createBuilder()` should be array of options (named `data_class`).

> `FormBuilder createFormBuilder(mixed $data = null, array $options = array())`
>
> mixed `$data` The initial data for the form
>
> array `$options`  Options for the form